# Workbook_SheetChange event triggers twice when it shouldn't

Tags: excel, vba

Below code that was in use for a while isn't working anymore.

I did a test in new sheet without other code with the same result.

We've recently moved to Office 365 and my current Excel version is 1902.
Unfortunately everyone here has the same version now, so I can't test it on an older one.
I mention this because I can't think of anything but this being due to a new bug?

Edit: I should add that this was used to prevent (re)moving rows or columns.

Edit: **What doesn't work: It triggers twice every time.** (I left this important part out after several edits)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal wks As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If ((Target.Address = Target.EntireRow.Address Or _
    Target.Address = Target.EntireColumn.Address)) Then

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .Undo
            .EnableEvents = True
            MsgBox "Do not modify the structure.", vbExclamation, "Notice"
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: in my Office 365 ProPlus Excel version 1902 build 11328.20420 it works

Comment: When you say: **isn't working anymore**, what do you mean? does it throw an error? runs but nothing happens?

Comment: @Zac oh my, I removed that before posting accidentally. It simply triggers twice, where first `Undo` removes the action users has made and second reinstates it.

Comment: I think @DisplayName suggestion should work for you

Answer (score 1):

you could try and turn it into a `SelectionChange` event

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If ((Target.Address = Target.EntireRow.Address Or _
    Target.Address = Target.EntireColumn.Address)) Then

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            Target.Cells(1, 1).Select
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
        MsgBox "Do not modify the structure.", vbExclamation, "Notice"

    End If

End Sub
```

that would preserve you from `Undo` usage and all its consequences